# Do I fit the scaler on X or X_train when I have train,dev and test sets?

Tags: python

Here is my data

```
X = X.reshape((-1, 784))
y = y.reshape((-1,1))
X_test = X_test.reshape((-1, 784))
y_test = y_test.reshape((-1,1))

X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, 
                                                  y, 
                                                  test_size=0.1, 
                                                  random_state=1)
```

Do I fit the `X` or `X_train` in the `.fit` ?

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(X_train)
```

or

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(X)
```

The transform will be as follows

```
X_train = scaler.transform(X_train)
X_val = scaler.transform(X_val)
y_test = scaler.transform(y_test)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use only the train data to avoid biasing and skewing. Some deeper explanation in this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/375165/scaling-separately-in-train-and-test-set) or in many other sources.

Answer (score 0):

fit will give you min and max value which is used on unseen datasets, you have to use fit on train , and transform on test and dev set

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
data = [[-1, 2], [-0.5, 6], [0, 10], [1, 18]]
```

doing fit on train data will give you min and max value which you need to used on new data 1.e test or dev

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler()

scaler.fit(data)

scaler.data_min_
#op
array([-1.,  2.])

scaler.data_max_
#op
array([ 1., 18.])

#now using formuala
x = (x-min(x))/(max(x)- min(x))
new_data = [[25,42]]

(25-(-1))/1-(-1)  # for 25 
#op
13.0

(42 - (2))/(18 - (2)) #for 42
#op
2.5

scaler.transform([[25,42]])  # it uses the min and max value which we get using fit
#op
array([[13. ,  2.5]])
```